# Laravel 5.1: get insert ids for each record inserted

Tags: php, laravel, insert

my application needs a custom tagging system. This means creating multiple records for each new tag, and then adding the id's of those records to a pivot table.

I can insert multiple records from an array using Laravels "insert":

```
    $tag_titles = explode(",", $tag_titles);

    foreach ($tag_titles as $tag_title) {
      $tags[] = array('tag_title' => $tag_title);

    }


    $tag = Tag::insert( $tags );
```

but now i need to know the id's that were created during the insert. Is there a way of doing this without making multiple calls to the DB to do each insert separately?

Thanks.

> so far I have tried

sync() method will only work for a single id :

```
$tag->content()->sync($tags);
```

After the insert, $tag is not an object, so $tag->id won't work

Comment: What kind of object is $tag?

Comment: $tag is the object created by the Tag model / insert. If $tag = Tag::create(), then $tag->id would be the last created id for the $tag object

Comment: but ::insert can create multiple records... i need an array of primary keys for those records

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a QueryBuilder instance to insert, in which case, you should be able to use  insertGetId

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insertGetId

Comment: does it return an array of ids for each record added? if it does its exactly what i'm looking for!

Comment: The issue is that insert allows bulk insert, but you can only get the id for the last insert (certainly in MySQL, maybe different in other database types).  You can however put insertGetId in a loop and append the result of each call to an array.  If you are inserting a large number of items, then you could use a transaction for the inserts, assuming you are using a db engine that supports transactions e.g. MySQL innodb